# Why it shows [deleted] next to my order detail's existing store view name?

Tags: store-view, order-details, pos

I have my orders placed via a POS app and everything has been working properly. However, at a tradeshow, I didn't collect my customers' addresses (to speed up the process), therefore the orders weren't synced to my admin site (as Magento requires every customer to have addresses) but rather stayed within the app.

When I resync those orders, they appeared on the admin site properly, however, I see it shows [deleted] next to my current existing store view name within each order detail: [image: [deleted] next to existing store view]
I have never deleted this store view though: [image: Current store view in Magento]

What does that mean? What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

The .phtml file which is rendering this information is on below path

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml

It calls below code to render store info

```
<?php if ($block->isSingleStoreMode() == false) : ?>
    <tr>
        <th><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Purchased From')) ?></th>
        <td><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getOrderStoreName(), ['br']) ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In the corresponding block file getOrderStoreName function is defined as below

```
public function getOrderStoreName()
{
    if ($this->getOrder()) {
        $storeId = $this->getOrder()->getStoreId();
        if ($storeId === null) {
            $deleted = __(' [deleted]');
            return nl2br($this->getOrder()->getStoreName()) . $deleted;
        }
        $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId);
        $name = [$store->getWebsite()->getName(), $store->getGroup()->getName(), $store->getName()];
        return implode('<br/>', $name);
    }

    return null;
}
```

From the above code it is clear that the **storeId** value is null and not getting stored in the `sales_order` table in the database. Please check in the database and confirm and check related customisations at code level for it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Rahul! Thank you for the details, I really appreciate that. However, we are in multi-store mode and I don’t see mention of that. Can you please assist further?